# Auto-capitalization of question titles

Tags: feature-request, questions, title, capitalization

Would it be possible to implement an auto-correction mechanism on the title box to make the first word always capitalized? It's not a big deal, but it could help those who are not familiar with capitalization in making a better impression, and would reduce the frequency of trivial edits like this.

Comment: Do we really need this? I see far less questions with a lower-case first word in the title than questions with *ALL CAPS PLZ HALP*.

Comment: Would be quite annoying in many cases particularly with language keywords: e.g. "class or struct: which is better?"

Comment: first word? why? If you are proposing capitalization of the **first letter** then why not automatically correct the entire title? obviously a joke, please leave our keen young (rep-wise) moderators something to do ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba I tried to think about possible exceptions, but maybe such cases could go back and override the auto-correction, sort of how you do in MS Word and the like

Comment: @mehow I'm a mod and I find this offensive ;) Seriously though, lowercase titles bother me a little bit, and even more suggested edits with only a case change

Comment: [convince me this is necessary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info)

Comment: Confirmation: is it really only the first letter of first word, or first letter of each word? Also, how about extreme case like title begins with "iOS" and language keyword? (Bathsheba has a good point)

Comment: Please don't adopt Microsoft's "the software is smarter than you are" attitude. Why should people who type their titles correctly be the ones who have to go back and do extra work to fix them? And who cares if they're "improperly" lowercased anyway? The site's logo is even improperly lowercased.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the question deserves an answer, not just comments. So I'll answer, repeating the comments.

1. There's no problem that needs solving. Most people capitalize their questions well enough.
2. Auto-capitalization may be wrong, corrupting correct titles. For example, the keywords `struct` and `class` must not be capitalized.
3. It's a better approach to trust the users to format their questions and answers. They normally know what they're doing better than any algorithm.

Comment: 4. Many truly intolerable titles are edited anyway